# How to print 2 elements of list per 1 table row in JSF

Tags: jsf-2

I have a list of objects of particular class. Each object has two fields: `id` and `value`. I have to display that list by JSF, two elements per row, like that:

```
id1 value1 id2 value2
id3 value3 id4 value4
id5 value5 id6 value6
```

I don't want them to be just thrown into there in random way. I was rather thinking about displaying it in some table (with 4 columns), so they won't look messy (if one value is shorter than other).

I thought about using `h:panelGroup`, but i can not use `c:forEach` as my list is not available at that point (And yes, I have tired, it prints nothing there). `ui:repeat` can not be used with `h:panelGroup`.

I don't think I can use `h:dataTable`, as I need two elements of list being printed in one row and `h:dataTable` is rather not created with something like that in mind.

What can I do?

(I am JSF-noob, or... rather worst: I **was** JSF-noob, then hadn't contact with it for long time)

Answer (score 1):

for solve this, you first have to group the list in pairs, then you can use ui:repetat + html table to print the results like:

```
@Named(value = "newJSFManagedBean")
@SessionScoped
public class NewJSFManagedBean implements Serializable {

    private List<String> cars;
    private List<List<String>> finalList;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of NewJSFManagedBean
     */
    public NewJSFManagedBean() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadCars() {
        //Load main list
        cars = new ArrayList<>();
        cars.add("Volvo");
        cars.add("Volvo1");
        cars.add("Volvo2");
        cars.add("Volvo3");
        cars.add("Volvo4");
        cars.add("Volvo5");
        cars.add("Volvo6");
        cars.add("Volvo7");
        cars.add("Volvo8");
        cars.add("Volvo9");
        //Gruping in pairs
        finalList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> groupList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String car : cars) {
            if (groupList.size() == 2) {
                finalList.add(groupList);
                groupList = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            groupList.add(car);
        }
        finalList.add(groupList);
    }

    public List<String> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    public void setCars(List<String> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    public List<List<String>> getFinalList() {
        return finalList;
    }

    public void setFinalList(List<List<String>> finalList) {
        this.finalList = finalList;
    }

}
```

and in the xhtml

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>VALUE</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>VALUE</th>
            </tr>

            <ui:repeat var="item"
                       value="#{newJSFManagedBean.finalList}">
                <tr>
                    <ui:repeat var="subItem"
                               value="#{item}">
                        <td>someId</td>
                        <td>#{subItem}</td>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </tr>
            </ui:repeat>


        </table>
```

result in :
[image: see]